# issue with add_month date using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, netezza

I am trying to use the add_month function but getting an error.  I want to get the number of visits between [CAL_DATE - 13 months] and [CAL_DATE]. The format of the dates are as following: 2007-14,  2010-05, 2009-04 and etc.  this is the error I am getting
"Bad time stamp external representation '2009-11"
and here is the code I am using.  I can't seem to figure out the issue.

```
CAL_DATE BETWEEN add_months(CAL_DATE,-13) AND CAL_DATE.
```

I am using netezza database.

Comment: can anyone help please?

Comment: What is `add_months`? Is that your own function or just a placeholder for something you need?

Comment: add_months is a Netezza or PostgreSQL function that is used to compare between Dates.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `add_months` expects a date as its first argument and returns a date. You don't have dates, you have YYYY-MM strings so you have two problems:

1. `add_months` won't know what to do with a YYYY-MM string.
2. BETWEEN won't know what to do with a date and a YYYY-MM string.

If you want to use `add_months` then you'll have to give it a date and convert the date it gives you to one of your YYYY-MM strings with something like this:

```
to_char(add_months((cal_date || '-01')::date, -13), 'yyyy-mm')
```

Appending `-01` to your strings should give you a string representation of the first of that month and you should be able to cast that to a `date` with `::date`. Then a `to_char` to convert the result of `add_months` back to your YYYY-MM format.

Alternatively, since `add_months` isn't really doing anything useful for you here, just use a PostgreSQL interval for the month adjustment:

```
to_char((cal_date || '-01')::date - interval '13 months', 'yyyy-mm')
```

Comment: thanks.  i initially had something like this: 2013-10-02 but i used  the substring function to remove the day portion of the date: SUBSTRING (cal_date, 1, 7).  so my question is, is there a way to keep the Year and the Month but replace the day with 01?

Comment: Why do you want to replace a day that isn't there? Your `cal_date`s just contain the year and month so where would a 02 day come from?

Comment: the original format for the date field is yyyy-mm-dd but i had remove the day portion so i can group the data by year and month only.  if i figure out how to replace 01 with with day portion then my problem will be solved.

Comment: I'm confused. Your `cal_date`s are YYYY-MM-DD but they're also YYYY-MM? Please update your question to reflect reality.

Comment: date_trunc('month',to_Date('2013-10-02','YYYY-MM-DD'))  will keep just the month and year

Comment: @Niederee: Yeah, that's another option but `date_trunc` gives you a `timestamp` back.

Comment: You can wrap it with `date` like `date(date_trunc('month',to_Date('2013-10-02','YYYY-MM-DD')))`